# how to remove default qualifier (") when line break (vbcrlf) is added in an expression in ssrs without touching reportserverconfig file?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-tablix

I am creating a summary CSV file in SSRS and have added VBCRLF for line breaks across the expression. Because of that I am getting " (double quotes) at the start of the string and one at the end of the string result set.

```
="1 RUN DATE:  "+Format(Globals!ExecutionTime,"MM/dd/yyyy")+"                    **************************************                                        PAGE      1" +vbcrlf+
    "  RUN TIME:  "+Format(Globals!ExecutionTime,"HH:mm:ss")+"                                EXTRACT RECORD COUNT                                                WR165R01   " + vbcrlf +
    "                                                                                                                                     "+ vbcrlf+
    "-                                                                                                                                    " +vbcrlf+
    "-                        GROUP NUMBER:  "+Parameters!GrpNum.Value+"                                                                                       "+vbcrlf+
    "                                     GROUP RECORD COUNT:         "+str(Fields!RECORD_COUNT.Value)+"                                                                 "+vbcrlf+
    "-                                                                                                                                    " +vbcrlf+
    "-                                                                                                                                    "+vbcrlf+
    "-                                                                                                                                    "+vbcrlf+
    "-                                                                                                                                    "+vbcrlf+
    "-                                                                                                                                    "+vbcrlf+
    "-                                                                                                                                    "+vbcrlf+
    "-                                                                                                                                    "+vbcrlf+
    "-                                                                                                                                    "+vbcrlf+
    "-                                                                                                                                    "+vbcrlf+
    "-                                                                                                                                    "+vbcrlf+
    "-                                                                                                                                    "+vbcrlf+
    "-                                                                                                                                    "+vbcrlf+
    "-                                                                                                                                    "+vbcrlf+
    "-                                                                                                                                    "+vbcrlf+
    "-                                                                                                                                    "+vbcrlf+
    "-                                                                                                                                    "+vbcrlf+
    "-                                                      TOTAL RECORD COUNT:        "+str(Fields!RECORD_COUNT.Value)+"                                                "+vbcrlf+
    "                                                       ***** CONFIDENTIAL *****                                                      "+vbcrlf+
    "                                                       ***** END OF REPORT *****                                                     "
```

Comment: Why are you trying to do this all in a single expression?  This is what the basic objects are for in SSRS...

Comment: @Steve-o169 : Since the final output is a  fixed length file, I had to do it in single expression.

Comment: Hi All, Please let me know if there is any method to fix this issue?

Comment: depending of how you are usint ssrs you can add rendering parameters to the render call , butt when you use the dashboard ttthere is no way